# Yii2 controller not allowing another action to guest user

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-rbac

I'm using Yii2 Advance application. I've `SiteController.php` where I've actions like `login`, `logout` & `index`. Here `login` is for Guest users and `index` & `logout` for logged-in users. Now I've created one more action called `reset` to provide Forgot Password functionality. But whenever I'm trying to call `reset` action its redirecting back me to login page.

Following is my controller:

```
namespace backend\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\web\Controller;
use common\models\LoginForm;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;

/**
 * Site controller
 */
class SiteController extends Controller {

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors() {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['login', 'error'],
                        'allow' => true
                    ],
                    [
                        'actions' => ['logout', 'index'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                    [
                        'allow' => true,
                        'actions' => ['reset'],
                        'roles' => ['?'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'logout' => ['post', 'get'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function actions() {
        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function actionIndex() {
        return $this->render('index');
    }

    public function actionLogin() {
        $this->layout = 'guest';

        if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }

        $model = new LoginForm();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
            return $this->goBack();
        } else {
            return $this->render('login', [
                        'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    public function actionLogout() {
        Yii::$app->user->logout();
        return $this->goHome();
    }

    public function actionReset() {        
        return $this->render('reset');
    }

}
```

I've added proper `roles & behaviours` for it but still its not working. I tried adding few more actions as well but in-fact its not allowing me to render any other action except login.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Remove  `'roles' => ['?'],`

Comment: Or `'actions' => ['login', 'error', 'reset'],`

Comment: @MuhammadShahzad: Both tried. But not working.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
namespace backend\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use common\models\LoginForm;

    class SiteController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * @inheritdoc
         */
        public function behaviors()
        {
            return [
                'access' => [
                    'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                    'rules' => [
                        [
                            'actions' => ['login', 'error', 'reset'],
                            'allow' => true,
                        ],
                        [
                            'actions' => ['logout', 'index'],
                            'allow' => true,
                            'roles' => ['@'],
                        ],

                    ],
                ],
                'verbs' => [
                    'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                    'actions' => [
                        'logout' => ['post'],
                    ],
                ],
            ];
        }

 /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
        ];
    }
       public function actionReset(){
            //die('You are here');
            return $this->render('reset');
        }

    ...
    }
```

My reset view code:

```
<?php

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $name string */
/* @var $message string */
/* @var $exception Exception */

use yii\helpers\Html;

$this->title = "Reset";
?>
<div class="site-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <div class="alert alert-success">
        Hi here you are without login
    </div>


</div>
```

[image]

Comment: It's working with `die` or `exit` but when I'm rendering through `return $this->render('reset');` then its redirecting to login page

Comment: `site/reset` view has nothing just simple `<h1>here</h1>` tag.

Comment: Plz check my ans and let me know whether it is correct way or not?

Comment: It is working on my side, I have update my answer. Pls let me know which yii2 version you are using? mine is 2.0.8

Comment: My Yii.2 version is 2.0.3

Comment: You should update your Yii2 version  run in project root directory `composer update`

Answer (score 1):

Solved it myself :)

There's condition in `vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Controller.php` i.e.

`if($this->action->id != 'login') { .. }`

And I changed it to

`if($this->action->id != 'login' && $this->action->id != 'reset') { .. }`

i.e.

```
public function beforeAction($action)
{ 
    // If user is guest then redirect to login page
    if($this->action->id != 'login' && $this->action->id != 'reset') {
        if(!isset($_SESSION['__id'])) {
           $this->redirect(array('site/login'));   
       }
    }
    if (parent::beforeAction($action)) {
        if ($this->enableCsrfValidation && Yii::$app->getErrorHandler()->exception === null && !Yii::$app->getRequest()->validateCsrfToken()) {
            throw new BadRequestHttpException(Yii::t('yii', 'Unable to verify your data submission.'));
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And its working.

Comment: So this is the issue

Comment: you can do this in site controller `beforeAction()`